# C# IndexOutOfRangeException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, indexoutofboundsexception

Having a slight c# problem here. 
I'm currently coding a small platformer-game with Unity and I had some raycasts which checked collisions and such.

Now, I started to clean the code a bit, by storing the results of those raycasts into an integer array, but I'm getting a IndexOutOfRangeException.

I've tried to read through my code many times but can't seem to find what is causing the problem. If someone can help me out, I would be really glad.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerRayCaster : MonoBehaviour {

    public float playerHeight = 1;
    public enum FeetState {Air, Ground};

    public FeetState playerFeetState = FeetState.Air;
    public int feetHitRays;
    public int behindHitRay;

    //Arrays of rays. value of 1 means that ray hits a target, 0 means that it does not hit.
    public int[] sideRays; // [0-3] = Left side. [4-8] = Right side.
    public int[] depthRays; // [0] = Away from camera. [1] = Towards camera.
    public int[] feetRays;

    public int counter;

    void Start(){
        sideRays = new int[8];
        depthRays = new int[2];
        feetRays = new int[3];

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        FeetRays();
        SideRays();
        BehindRay();
    }

    //Rays, which check if the character is bumping into an object, left or right.
    void SideRays(){

        float rayLength = 0.4f;
        counter = 0;

        //Left side rays.
        for(int rayHeight = 0 ; rayHeight>=-4 ; rayHeight-=1 , counter++){
            Debug.Log(sideRays[counter]);
            if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position-new Vector3(0,rayHeight/2,0), new Vector3(-1,0,0),rayLength)){
                sideRays[counter] = 1;
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position-new Vector3(0,rayHeight/2,0), new Vector3(-rayLength,0,0), Color.green);
            }
            else{
                sideRays[counter] = 0;
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position-new Vector3(0,rayHeight/2,0), new Vector3(-rayLength,0,0), Color.yellow);
            }
        }

        //Right side rays.
        for(int rayHeight = 0;rayHeight>=-4;rayHeight-=1,counter++){
            if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position-new Vector3(0,rayHeight/2,0), new Vector3(1,0,0),rayLength)){
                sideRays[counter] = 1;
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position-new Vector3(0,rayHeight/2,0), new Vector3(rayLength,0,0), Color.green);
            }
            else{
                sideRays[counter] = 0;
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position-new Vector3(0,rayHeight/2,0), new Vector3(rayLength,0,0), Color.yellow);
            }
        }
    }

    //Three rays, which check if the characters feet are on the ground or not.
    void FeetRays(){
        feetHitRays = 0;
        float rayLength = 0.2f;
        //Shoots three rays down from player.
        for(float i=-0.7f;i<=0.7f;i+=0.7f){

            if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position-new Vector3(i/2,0,0), new Vector3(0,-1,0),rayLength)){
                feetHitRays++;
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position-new Vector3(i/2,0,0), new Vector3(0,-rayLength,0), Color.green);
            }
            else{
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position-new Vector3(i/2,0,0), new Vector3(0,-rayLength,0), Color.red);
            }
        }

        //Sets the feet state.
        if(feetHitRays==0)
        {
            playerFeetState = PlayerRayCaster.FeetState.Air;
        }
        else{
            playerFeetState = PlayerRayCaster.FeetState.Ground;
        }       
    }
    //Shoots a raycast in z-direction from the character, to check for door access.
    void BehindRay(){

        behindHitRay = 0;
        float rayLength = 2;

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector3(0,0,1), rayLength)){ //Away from camera
            behindHitRay = 1;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, new Vector3(0,0,rayLength), Color.green);
        }
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector3(0,0,-1), rayLength)){ // Towards camera.
            behindHitRay = -1;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, new Vector3(0,0,-rayLength), Color.green);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the line that gives me the exception:

```
sideRays[counter] = 1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sideRays` is being initialized in `Start()` but I don't see where it is ever run. Is it possible `sideRays` is never initialized?

Comment: what does Debug.Log(sideRays[counter]) read before the exception is thrown?

Comment: It is run in Update, it is a unity function which is called every frame. Debug.Log shows just "0".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is the problem:

```
for(int rayHeight = 0 ; rayHeight>=-4 ; rayHeight-=1 , counter++)
```

You're basically doing that twice, and that means *10* iterations, whereas your array is initialized like this:

```
sideRays = new int[8];
```

You may well want:

```
// Note the > instead of >=
for (int rayHeight = 0; rayHeight > -4; rayHeight--, counter++)
```

(As an aside, I'd *very strongly* recommend that you don't use public fields, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Public fields are used in so much Unity code because of the decision to serialize/display them in the Editor.  The [SerializeField] attribute isn't used in example code, like it should be.

Comment: Thanks, what a classic mistake. I use public fields just for debugging, I can see the values in Unity Editor while running the game. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 1):

You declare sideRays with a size of 8, but it looks from a quick glance at your loops that counter can get as high as 10.

Answer (score 1):

Check your bounds on `for(int rayHeight = 0;rayHeight>=-4;rayHeight-=1,counter++){` You'll end up accessing the array 5 times for each loop and you've defined your array to have 8 items. Accessing 9 and 10 will throw an exception.